# It is possible to cancel Firestore write operations?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on location tracking app. I will update the user location data to database every 10 minutes. For instance, Source Location is A, Destination Location is D.

If user reached  location B, I will update last location to B. When user reached C and then D, suppose if there is loss in internet connectivity, the C and D location details will not be saved in database.

Then if internet works it may write first D and after C location,  it is not in correct order. so the last location in database will be C instead of D.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to cancel a pending write.

I can think of two options:

1. Use a database transaction and base the new value for the document on the existing value.
2. Use security rules to ensure that only valid transitions are allowed. A typical approach here could be to add a (client-side) timestamp to each write operation, and reject writes where the timestamp is too old.